Isekai manga where the villainess has hair drills and she has a butler
I once stumbled upon this manga long ago.
It revolves around this villainess, where she acts like a villainess, also tries to antagonize the female protagonist but fails to do so.
Rather she was seen by the female protagonist as someone confident and strong but also kind.
The villainess has a butler who seemed to be her love interest (?)
But he knows her shenanigans, and attempts to become the best villainess in history, but also seeing her fail because she's subconsciously kind

Is it a science fiction or fantasy story? This site is supposed to be for science fiction and fantasy.

I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to be about science fiction or fantasy.

What… uh… what are hair drills?

@Lexible staple hairdo of villainesses in japanesse manga. Google gives appropriate picture even without clicking any links

@MateuszL Oh dang! My lack of interest in magical girl anime catches me out! Thank you!

@user14111 It's easy to miss, but the question is tagged isekai, so that's one fantasy element.

@Laurel A tag is enough? So all you have to do is tag your question fantasy-genre and that makes it on topic?

@user14111 - We've had this discussion before. While I favour the "at least one thing" principle (e.g. that there should be at least a single discernible fact about the ID that is fantastical) the consensus of opinion was that merely asserting that it's on-topic is sufficient

I found it. It's an isekai fantasy manga.
The Daughter of the Albert House Wishes for Ruin (アルバート家の令嬢は没落をご所望です).

Noble’s daughter Mary Albert, in the middle of the school opening ceremony, remembers that this world was an otome game she played in her previous life, and she turns out to be a character from that game. The Mary inside the game was a villain, harassing and interfering with the heroine, and was met with destruction at the end – the so called ‘villainous girl’s downfall route’. And so the obvious reaction is ‘This isn’t a joke!’ and carefully avoids the destruction end…… or not!


Answers are expected to contain sufficient detail that they clearly justify why they are correct. Your answer is rather brief and doesn't contain a link to the source (eg.: this link) Please [edit] the answer, then the question to demonstrate a fantasy or science-fiction aspect of the story.

Thanks! Will do that from now on

Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
